# Problems with AcquireRequestState

Tags: c#, iis-7, iis-7.5, global-asax

I've got a mistery thing.

I've wrotten some code on Application_AcquireRequestState to rewrite some js,css and images.

With Visual Studio 2010 all works fine (AcquireRequestState is fired in each file request) but when I go to production (IIS 7.5 with Windows 2008). AcquireRequestState fires a few times (for the most of de file requests, AcquireRequestState does not fires).

Do you know why?

Here is my code:

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).ToLower();
    string ArgName = Util.GetArgName(); //ie. john                
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ArgName))
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("/home/"))
        {
            sitebase.GetPhysicalPathFile(Request, ArgName);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've seen that in IIS 7.5, BeginRequest, AcquireRequestState,... never rises when the request is a fake path like ("www.mydomain.com/script/myinexistentfile.js") but in Visual Studio 2010 yes.

I've added the next in web.config but with no result

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    ...
</system.webServer>


What happends? It's a IIS 7.5 bug?

Thank you very much

Comment: Was the problem that the IIS application pool was running in Classic mode instead of Integrated mode?